# Unable to update POJOs to solr directly

Tags: java, json, solrj

My intention is to update solr using POJOs. I am trying to update a field(id) using solrServer and `addBean` method.

The program is getting executed properly but I am not able to see my update in solr. Please let me know what might be wrong in the code. I also tried using `SolrInputDocument` to add the fields and it is working fine(commented code in the snippet). It will be very helpful for me if you can please provide an answer with respect to adding POJOs to solr directly. This is the code:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;
public class Item {
            @Field
            String id;
        }

package stockjournalist;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import org.apache.solr.*;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.DirectXmlRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.LukeRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.SolrPing;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.LukeResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FacetField;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.UpdateResponse;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.util.ClientUtils;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.apache.solr.common.util.XML;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.FacetParams;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.*;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;

public class JsonSample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, SolrServerException{
        JsonSample js = new JsonSample();
        js.insertOneDoc();
    }
    private SolrServer getSolrServer(){ 
            String server = "http://localhost:8983/solr";
            SolrServer solrServer = null;
            solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(server); 
            return solrServer;  
    } 
    public void insertOneDoc() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
          Item item = new Item();
          item.id = "5137158701";
          SolrServer server = getSolrServer();
          server.addBean(item);
          server.commit();
          //String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr";
          //HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer(urlString);
          //SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
          //doc.addField("id", "552199");
          //doc.addField("name", "See if 513715870 is available in the index.");
          //solr.add(doc);
          //solr.commit();
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please can you

1. check your solrj version and solr version. The have to be the same!
2. print the return of update:
   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.**UpdateResponse** from SolrServer and past the response here in order to help you.

   ```
    public void insertOneDoc() throws SolrServerException, IOException {
   Item item = new Item();
   item.id = "5137158701";
   SolrServer server = getSolrServer();

   //DEBUG
   UpdateResponse resp= server.addBean(item);
   System.out.println("SolrResponse:"+ r.getStatus() + r.getElapsedTime());
   for( Entry<String, Object> o: r.getResponse()){
       System.out.println("SolrResponse - response :"+ o.getKey() + o.getValue().toString());
   }
   server.commit();
   ```

   }
3. see logs in solr admin http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~logging
4. share your schema.xml, solrconfig.xml

Answer (score 0):

Although the post is old, I came across it while having the same needs.

So for what it's worth as there is no `updateBean()` method, and as you have the id of the existing document in index, you can first delete the existing doc by providing its id to the `deleteById` method, and then add the bean as usual via `addBean` method :

```
solrClient.deleteById(item.id);
solrClient.addBean(item);
```

*Please note: HttpSolrServer has been deprecated in favour of HttpSolrClient*